# How do I convert multiple videos into one image sequence using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two videos that I wish to convert into a single consecutive image sequence, properly numbered and labelled. They were .mkv files from different origins, converted to .mp4.

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mkv -c copy vid1.mp4 && ffmpeg -i vid2.mkv -c copy vid2.mp4
```

This is how I wish to convert the videos into images:

**Input**: vid1.mp4 (10s) + vid2.mp4 (20s)

Convert to an image sequence at a rate of 5 image frames per second of video.

**Output**:

From vid1: img0001.png to img0050.png (10s --> 50 frames)

From vid2: img0051.png to img0151.png (20s --> 100 frames)

How can I do this? I tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -map v -vf fps=5 img%04d.png
```

but only vid1 was converted. I tried `*:v` to select all inputs but that syntax doesn't seem to be valid.

The above are all done on the Windows command line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the concat filter.

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex [0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,fps=5 img%04d.png
```

Comment: Two of my videos are of a different resolution, but I don't want to resize as I want each output image to have the same resolution as its corresponding source video. Is there anything I can do about that?